# glassfish not logging after deploy

Tags: maven, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

We just turned our project into a Maven project and since that we have problem with the logging. before that everything was in the log files (System.in/err etc) and i even could see them in the netbeans glassfish tab. But now the deploy "stucks" at Initializing part:

```
Undeploying ...
Distributing D:\ExtMonTool\trunk\src\target\extmon-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to [GlassFish Server 3+]
Initializing...
```

The app is deployed and works but there is no log in the server.log or netbeans

Any idea what should i change where should i look for the problem?

Comment: war packaging tree to show will be useful

Comment: i edited the question now it contains pom.xml

Comment: I mean files and directory structure inside your war

Comment: I also included the content of the war, tell me if u need a specific folders content from the war

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the [links to codeviewer.org no longer work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345443/what-should-happen-to-questions-using-codeviewer-org-for-sharing-code). Without these links, the question has no clear [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises after these lines in the log:

```
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:richfaces_showcase]
```

so, I guess the problem is caused by `richfaces-showcase`, when Hibernate is trying to clean up the connection pool.

If you're not using the `richfaces-showcase` anyway (which you're probably not), you could exclude it from your dependencies, so it cannot cause any trouble.

By running the `dependency:tree` goal, you can see, that the `richfaces-distribution` contains the following:

```
+- org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-api:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
   +- org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-ui:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
   +- org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-api:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
   +- org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-impl:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
   +- org.richfaces.examples:richfaces-showcase:war:tomcat6:4.3.2.Final:compile
   +- org.richfaces.archetypes:richfaces-archetype-simpleapp:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
```

Just replace the `richfaces-distribution` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

with the contained dependencies, **without** the `richfaces-showcase`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**Another** way to solve the problem (**but I'm not sure of this, it's only an assumption**) would be to make a hibernate configuration for the `richfaces-showcase`. (I think this is needed because of the GlassFish server, the default configuration in the richfaces distribution is for Tomcat: `org.richfaces.examples:richfaces-showcase:war:tomcat6:4.3.2.Final:compile`).